# PHP/MySQL > Update field when link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I need help with a simple code which will update a field (+1) in MySQL when a link on my website is clicked. This is for a "Report" button on my comments database.

So I can see how many times a comment has been 'reported'. It's important that the script doesn't redirect or load a new page, just echos a message or a JS alert.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX.

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO. The better you explain your questions, the accurate answers you will get :) You can also edit your questions again and interact with those who answer via comments below their answers :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you looking for a general outline of what you could do, actual code (someone here do it for you), or what?

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "update `table` set `increment` = `increment` + 1 where `link` = '".$link."'";
```

This is just the query. You should look into jquery ajax to handle the request

In some.php you need a way to read the post.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['clicked_row']))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE $row_to_update SET increment = increment + 1 WHERE id = '".$_POST['clicked_row']."'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Assuming you send the row id in your ajax request, which is in the data parameter of the jquery post, your HTML would need to be something like `<a href="javascript:increment(row_id);">Add click</a>` so the jquery call knows what row to send to some.php

Comment: This is a really fantastic way to prevent participation on this site. Click the minus arrow for what reason? He said SIMPLE. Based on his question it looked like he did not know you can just increment counts on a database table by stating 'row = row + 1' so the answer is valid. If not, what? The entire jquery statement plus post script for php and mysql? No table names were provided, so you have to get generic. Why then is not every answer on this question docked? Seriously, people.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can do the query but how do I run it when a link is clicked?

Comment: @Kai Qing - Calm down, it's not the end of the world if you get a down vote. I didn't down vote you, and wouldn't have as it is, but in the grand scheme of things it'll come out in the wash. :)

Comment: jurka gave the best example in my opinion. I'll update my post with a generic PHP sample for handling the request

Comment: @Jared - I would understand if I left a comment like "Duh ever heard of jquery" or something totally useless but my answer was relevant to something commonly overlooked by many developers. Yeah it wasn't a complete example, but the question did not specify such things. So instead of writing a 3 page html php js example I wrote a response to the only part of the question that looked direct. I, not unlike many people here, work on this stuff professionally every day and answer questions in between commits or while compiling. A pointless vote down just gives one more reason to never return.

Comment: We are all in the same boat, save for the 30 or so employees of SO. If you really think you've been wronged, you can try flagging your own answer, see what the mods say (?). But, my interpretation is, it's not worth getting that worked up about. A down vote doesn't say anything about you personally, unless you let it get to you.

Comment: Well, if you're building SQL from strings and include `$_POST` without escaping, every downvote is deserved. Atleast add a warning about SQL Injection. But I agree that comment should be added with a downvote. Why is this not yet obligatory on SO?

Comment: @Konerak - When it was down voted, it only contained the first two lines. I don't know why it was down voted, but the code you are talking about (with the $_POST going directly into the query) was not added until later. Of course, you are right; it should have mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clicked_row']) added in there.

Comment: True for the escape, but not unlike a field called increment, you mostly assume people will replace the obvious filler with actual methods. Probably not a good assumption considering my original complaint about the question, but it is one more of those things that convert it from an initially simple answer to the need to write out the huge complete version that you provided. I myself use frameworks, so my standard escape method would not make sense here. I left it out because I have heard complaints about real escape and would never suggest something like addslashes. Anyhow thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

An outline of what you could do. I made some assumptions, and chose GET using the URL method instead of POST; edit to taste, if you prefer to use POST.

Another note - you may want to have a flags table, so as to allow you to follow who has flagged who, maybe let them add a comment, etc... Just a thought.

This is just meant to give you an idea how you could do what you ask. I haven't tested the code, so buyer beware. This is just a starting point.

**view.php**

This is where you have the link that the end user would click on to activate the flag script. Somewhere in your markup, you would have something like...

```
<a class="flag" href="flag.php?comment=100">Flag</a>
```

Then, within view.php content, you would have the click event code that attempts a jQuery asynchronous javascript request ($.ajax() in this case, could be $.get or $.post, or another library altogether like MooTools or Prototype).

The example demonstrates that the server will return JSON-formatted text in the data argument, which is then evaluated to check what the server responded with (success? failure? partial success? login required?). See http://json.org/.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.flag').click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.error == -1) {
                    // Not logged in, redirect to login page.
                    window.location = 'login.php';
                } else if (data.flagged == 1 && data.count != -1) {
                    // Success! With a count too.
                    alert('Comment flagged ('+data.count+' times flagged).');
                } else {
                    switch(data.error) {
                        case 1:
                            alert('Comment not found');
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            alert('Comment not flagged due to an update error.');
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            alert('Comment flagged but count not returned.');
                        break;
                        default:
                            alert('There was a general error flagging the comment.');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Comment not flagged; general send error.');
            }
        });

        // Call these to prevent the a tag from redirecting
        // the browser to the a-tags href url.
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

**flag.php**

flag.php is the server page that allows you to run your mysql query, using PHP of course, and then respond with some JSON-formatted text. The content (text) returned by the page would look something like:

```
{"flagged":1,"count":15,"error":0}
```

This would indicate to your calling page (in the browser) that the comment was flagged, has been flagged 15 times (bad, bad comment), and that there were no errors.

**THIS IS IMPORTANT**: This is *not* equivalent to HTML. This type of text is data and is parsed back into a Javascript object on response to the $.ajax() function. So, don't put any HTML in there around it, since that's not what you are supposed to do. See http://www.json.org/example.html for examples.

```
<?php

// Need to output JSON headers and try to prevent caching.
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Our JSON array to return
//   - flagged would be 1 = success, 0 = failure
//   - count would return the # flags, with -1 no return #
//   - error code, see comments for description
$json = array('flagged'=>0,'count'=>-1,'error'=>0);

// Your logged in check code goes here 
// you don't want non-logged in people doing this

// Here, however you test to find out if someone is logged in,
// check and return a -1 error to redirect the login.    
if (!$logged_in) {
    // error -1 = not logged in, redirect browser
    $json['error'] = -1;
    exit(echo(json_encode($json)));
}

// Your mysql connection code goes here

$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['comment']);

if (empty($comment) || !is_numeric($comment)) {
    // error 1 = comment id not found
    $json['error'] = 1;
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("
UPDATE comments 
SET flags = flags+1 
WHERE commentID = $comment
");
    if (!$result) {
        $json['flagged'] = 0;
        // error 2 = update error
        $json['error'] = 2;
    } else {
        $json['flagged'] = 1;
        $count = mysql_query("
SELECT flags 
FROM comments 
WHERE commentID = $comment 
LIMIT 0, 1
");
        if ($count) {
            $query = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);
            $json['count'] = $query['count'];
        } else {
            // error 3 = updated but did not get count
            $json['error'] = 3;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: And this is answer you should actually mark as an accepted answer. Complete and correct. Very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Qing. This type of question can be problematic, whereas a longer, more detailed answer is needed, but (in general) early answers get up voted more often. So it's a tradeoff: Give a concise or partial answer and get a few votes, or a longer, detailed, time-consuming answer and risk no one ever sees it, or the poster abandons the question. Since I had the time (we are facing extreme winter weather where I am at, so I'm home instead of working), I went ahead and did this as an exercise. What would have been even nicer would have been to test it, but I don't have a server setup right now.

Comment: @Kai Qing - See, even if you spend some time on your answer and try to work it out, it doesn't always end in up votes and points. So, if you get bent out of shape over a single down vote, you won't last long on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't simple.

You should look here:
http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php

Your sql will look something like this.

```
"UPDATE post SET flagcount = flagcount + 1 WHERE postID = {$myPostID}"
```

Comment: might be worth mentioning that he can use a library to handle the AJAX operations, ie jQuery Mootools, etc

Comment: Actually, this is really simple. Your link is quite nice, but a bit outdated.

Comment: Yes, jQuery and MooTools are nice too.

Comment: I give you a plus one for being the only OTHER person who gave the query example, which is what I thought the question was about. How did you manage to not get stabbed for it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should look for ajax make an POST request to some of your php scripts which upgrades the answer in database. Something like this in jquery ?

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "some.php", // page where insertion to database should have made
       data: "name=John",
       success: function(msg){
         alert("Counter updated" );
       }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to send an AJAX request:

```
$.post('yourScript.php', {commentID: yourCommentId});
```

The second argument is the request data. Change that to fit your needs. If you want to execute a JavaScript function after the request has been completed:

```
$.post('yourScript.php', {commentID: yourCommentId}, function(data) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I just use a form?

```
<form method="post" action="report.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="report">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="report">
</form>
```

And then have the query in the report.php file?

Comment: Yes, but that'd redirect to `report.php` and you'd have to redirect back to the page that the form was on. Look in to jQuery and `$.ajax`.

Comment: Humm, thinking about it: I kinda like the idea of it redirecting to a new page now, I think I will have a textbox so the user can submit a reason why they reported it :)

Comment: you can also have jquery pull up a box that has the text field in it. using $('#your_form').toggle(); would show and hide it on click then you can fetch the message and field id with var message = $('#text_area').val(); var id = $('#field_id').val(); then add those vars to the jquery data parameter. This assumes your text area has an id of "text_area" and the field to increment has a hidden input id of "field_id"